# Magento 2 - Search only by the product name in Mini Search in header

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, custom-options

**Search only by the product name**

The search engine is also almost completely unusable. You search for something like "`wright wrench set`" and it returns `4712 items`. Instead of narrowing results, it's including all words in all parts of the description.

[image]